# How to get AllJoyn byte[] property

Tags: c#, windows-10-universal, alljoyn

I have an AllJoyn property like this

```
<property name="DeviceAddresses" type="ay" access="read">
```

I a Windows 10 UWP app when I try to read it - I get success - but I don't know how to get out the value from the result
Code looks like this:

```
var vProperty = pInterface.GetProperty(propertyName);

if (vProperty == null) return null;
var result = await vProperty.ReadValueAsync();

if (result.Status.IsSuccess) 
{
    if (vProperty.TypeInfo.Type == TypeId.Uint8Array) 
    {
        byte[] Erg = result.Value ???
    }
}
```

The property value is created via

```
object o = Windows.Foundation.PropertyValue.CreateUInt8Array(value);
```

But I found no way (casting or so) the get the bytes out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [DeviceProviders](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotMorten.AllJoyn.DeviceProviders/) to access AllJoyn methods. It uses

```
IAsyncOperation<InvokeMethodResult> InvokeAsync(IList<object> @params);
```

to get the server response. It looks similar to what your `ReadValueAsync()` returns. But not quite the same. This is how I access the bytes.

```
InvokeMethodResult result = await MyAllJoynMethod.InvokeAsync(new List<object> { "parameter", 2 });
if (result.Status.IsSuccess)
{
    var resultList = result.Values as IList<object>;
    foreach (var resultListItem in resultList)
    {
        var pairs = resultListItem as IList<KeyValuePair<object, object>>;
        foreach (var pair in pairs)
        {
            var key = pair.Key as string; //<- type string taken from MyAllJoynMethod definition
            var variant = pair.Value as AllJoynMessageArgVariant;//<- type AllJoynMessageArgVariant taken from MyAllJoynMethod definition (variant)

            if (variant.TypeDefinition.Type == TypeId.Uint8Array)
            {
                var array8 = j as IList<object>;
                foreach (byte b in array8)
                {
                    // do something with b
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: If you do not want to program it yourself you can use [OpenAlljoynExplorer](https://github.com/LukeOwlclaw/AllJoynMediaController/tree/master/OpenAlljoynExplorer). Not sure if byte arrays are actually supported, yet.